# How to implement iOS 7 style top tab bar or navigation bar on Android?

Tags: android, ios7

On iOS 7, there is a tab bar/navigation bar like below image

[image: iOS 7 Tab Bar]

Is there a control similar to the style of it on Android? I did see some apps implemented this styled navigation bar.

Comment: a puppy dies every time you implement iOS UI on Android :) You might need to look at http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html

Comment: not if it's only a tiny bit. In this case, a navigation bar. It's mostly safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control I described is actually called SegmentedControl which does have Android implementation. Below are a few of them:

```
https://github.com/hoang8f/android-segmented-control
https://github.com/peshkira/android_segmented_control
https://github.com/nairteashop/SegmentedControl
```

Hope someone find it helpful

Answer (score 2):

I agree you should not implement IOS features in Android.

Also I don't know where you got the picture for the IOS app, but an IOS app has a tab bar controller which shows its tabs at the bottom of the sreen. It also has a navigation controller which does in no way look like your screenshot.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html

That being said you can use tabs in the actionbar. http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html

Comment: I am aware of this tab bar in Android. But really I like the style of iOS 7 better. I guess there is no existing, off the shelf solution. I'll have to figure it out myself.

Comment: There is no off the shelf solution, but you could do it yourself. However you will be working against the framework. You can for instance use the fragmantManager to swap fragments at any time. This way you could just put some images or buttons at the bottom and swap the fragment when you click them.